# Set Section name as a mark for Fancyhdr header

Tags: fancyhdr, preamble, header, section-titles

I am using the `fancyhdr` package in my code and the preamble looks like this

```
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries}
```

Question is I want to add the **Section** name on the header of the odd pages on the left with the title not being all in uppercase.
For short, how can I change the `\rightmark` layout to appear not in all uppercases the same way I did for the `\chaptermark`?
I can't access the manual for some reason, I would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe: `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}` and `\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}`?

Comment: Yeah sorry @esdd, I completely forgot to be specific about what I wanted to change of the default section layout? Got it right now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```latex
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
```

to the preamble. Note that both `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` are still uppercased for header entries in TOC, LOF, LOT, bibliography etc. To avoid this use `\nouppercase` in `\fancyhead`:

```latex
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}% <- added
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}% <- changed
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}}% <- changed
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]